# Combine GRangesList with unified breakpoints

Tags: r, genomicranges

I'm looking to merge a list of 6 GRanges objects into one, with the resulting table have a common set of breakpoints across all 6 objects as shown in Figure 1 below.  I've tried to do this using `findOverlaps()`, however the this is equivalent to a `left_join` (or right depending how you set it up), which doesn't exactly take both coordinate sets into account.

I've experimented with `plyranges` however, these duplicate the row coordinates rather than breaking them into individual breakpoints, and I'm not exactly sure what's happening with the metadata. Example below:

Any suggestions on how to combine the sets ?  I use GenomicRanges, but I'm open to other suggestions since the data can be coerced to a `data.frame`, etc.

thank you,

Concept figure and data example:

[image]
Figure 1: Depiction of genomic segments in three samples (S1..S3), along a chromosome region.  The unified breakpoint ranges are marked by the black vertical lines, labeled 1..9.

Example using `plyranges`:

```
3   > library(GenomicRanges)
4   > library(tidyverse)
5   > library(plyranges)
6   *** output flushed ***
7   > data(grL)
8   > grL[1:2]
9   GRangesList object of length 2:
10  $A
11  GRanges object with 14212 ranges and 7 metadata columns:
12            seqnames            ranges strand |        Type X.log10.q.value
13               <Rle>         <IRanges>  <Rle> | <character>       <numeric>
14        [1]        1     564424-846680      * |         Amp               0
15        [2]        1     852863-974841      * |         Amp               0
16        [3]        1    986491-1565745      * |         Amp               0
17        [4]        1   1566563-2719525      * |         Amp               0
18        [5]        1   2728545-2761325      * |         Amp               0
19        ...      ...               ...    ... .         ...             ...
20    [14208]       22 50750387-50763701      * |         Del        1.129787
21    [14209]       22 50780464-50885937      * |         Del        2.941190
22    [14210]       22 50887704-51067512      * |         Del        0.011509
23    [14211]       22 51067512-51173133      * |         Del        0.400633
24    [14212]       22 51174234-51178205      * |         Del        0.480761
25              a.score           b.score   c.score      cohort     subtype
26            <numeric>         <numeric> <numeric> <character> <character>
27        [1]  0.163684          1.322534  0.054545    NYC        A
28        [2]  0.137531          1.689206  0.036364    NYC        A
29        [3]  0.064422          0.889654  0.036364    NYC        A
30        [4]  0.092361          1.195796  0.036364    NYC        A
31        [5]  0.101790          0.881394  0.054545    NYC        A
32        ...       ...               ...       ...         ...         ...
33    [14208]  0.068896          0.305572  0.181818    NYC        A
34    [14209]  0.112202          0.305572  0.181818    NYC        A
35    [14210]  0.015748          0.251801  0.181818    NYC        A
36    [14211]  0.037401          0.251801  0.181818    NYC        A
37    [14212]  0.039369          0.278090  0.181818    NYC        A
38    -------
39    seqinfo: 24 sequences from an unspecified genome; no seqlengths
40
41  $B
42  GRanges object with 25101 ranges and 7 metadata columns:
43            seqnames            ranges strand |        Type X.log10.q.value
44               <Rle>         <IRanges>  <Rle> | <character>       <numeric>
45        [1]        1     564424-835336      * |         Amp               0
46        [2]        1    837386-1458139      * |         Amp               0
47        [3]        1   1464470-1555673      * |         Amp               0
48        [4]        1   1556444-1565745      * |         Amp               0
49        [5]        1   1566563-2633368      * |         Amp               0
50        ...      ...               ...    ... .         ...             ...
51    [25097]       22 50710971-50742016      * |         Del        0.926994
52    [25098]       22 50780464-50885937      * |         Del        1.208032
53    [25099]       22 50887704-50914027      * |         Del        0.825840
54    [25100]       22 50915850-51173133      * |         Del        0.844370
55    [25101]       22 51174234-51218950      * |         Del        0.893049
56              a.score           b.score   c.score      cohort     subtype
57            <numeric>         <numeric> <numeric> <character> <character>
58        [1]  0.263871          0.408836  0.269231    NYC        B
59        [2]  0.239878          0.400169  0.250000    NYC        B
60        [3]  0.262476          0.436118  0.250000    NYC        B
61        [4]  0.223937          0.400252  0.230769    NYC        B
62        [5]  0.271884          0.451085  0.250000    NYC        B
63        ...       ...               ...       ...         ...         ...
64    [25097]  0.224858          0.350757  0.346154    NYC        B
65    [25098]  0.247760          0.362135  0.365385    NYC        B
66    [25099]  0.214448          0.338461  0.384615    NYC        B
67    [25100]  0.216530          0.338461  0.384615    NYC        B
68    [25101]  0.220694          0.378862  0.346154    NYC        B
69    -------
70    seqinfo: 24 sequences from an unspecified genome; no seqlengths
71
72  > a <- join_overlap_left(grL[[2]], grL[[1]])
73  > a
74  GRanges object with 73802 ranges and 14 metadata columns:
75            seqnames            ranges strand |      Type.x X.log10.q.value.x
76               <Rle>         <IRanges>  <Rle> | <character>         <numeric>
77        [1]        1     564424-835336      * |         Amp                 0
78        [2]        1     564424-835336      * |         Amp                 0
79        [3]        1    837386-1458139      * |         Amp                 0
80        [4]        1    837386-1458139      * |         Amp                 0
81        [5]        1    837386-1458139      * |         Amp                 0
82        ...      ...               ...    ... .         ...               ...
83    [73798]       22 50915850-51173133      * |         Del          0.844370
84    [73799]       22 50915850-51173133      * |         Del          0.844370
85    [73800]       22 50915850-51173133      * |         Del          0.844370
86    [73801]       22 51174234-51218950      * |         Del          0.893049
87    [73802]       22 51174234-51218950      * |         Del          0.893049
88            a.score.x           b.score.x   c.score.x    cohort.x   subtype.x
89            <numeric>           <numeric>   <numeric> <character> <character>
90        [1]  0.263871            0.408836    0.269231    NYC        B
91        [2]  0.263871            0.408836    0.269231    NYC        B
92        [3]  0.239878            0.400169    0.250000    NYC        B
93        [4]  0.239878            0.400169    0.250000    NYC        B
94        [5]  0.239878            0.400169    0.250000    NYC        B
95        ...       ...                 ...         ...         ...         ...
96    [73798]  0.216530            0.338461    0.384615    NYC        B
97    [73799]  0.216530            0.338461    0.384615    NYC        B
98    [73800]  0.216530            0.338461    0.384615    NYC        B
99    [73801]  0.220694            0.378862    0.346154    NYC        B
100   [73802]  0.220694            0.378862    0.346154    NYC        B
101                Type.y X.log10.q.value.y a.score.y           b.score.y
102           <character>         <numeric> <numeric>           <numeric>
103       [1]         Del          0.006434  0.007874            0.201368
104       [2]         Amp          0.000000  0.163684            1.322534
105       [3]         Del          0.006434  0.007874            0.201368
106       [4]         Amp          0.000000  0.163684            1.322534
107       [5]         Amp          0.000000  0.137531            1.689206
108       ...         ...               ...       ...                 ...
109   [73798]         Amp          0.000000  0.000000            0.000000
110   [73799]         Del          0.011509  0.015748            0.251801
111   [73800]         Del          0.400633  0.037401            0.251801
112   [73801]         Amp          0.000000  0.000000            0.000000
113   [73802]         Del          0.480761  0.039369            0.278090
114             c.score.y    cohort.y   subtype.y
115             <numeric> <character> <character>
116       [1]    0.018182    NYC        A
117       [2]    0.054545    NYC        A
118       [3]    0.018182    NYC        A
119       [4]    0.054545    NYC        A
120       [5]    0.036364    NYC        A
121       ...         ...         ...         ...
122   [73798]    0.000000    NYC        A
123   [73799]    0.181818    NYC        A
124   [73800]    0.181818    NYC        A
125   [73801]    0.000000    NYC        A
126   [73802]    0.181818    NYC        A
127   -------
128   seqinfo: 24 sequences from an unspecified genome; no seqlengths
129
130 > sessionInfo()
131 R version 4.0.5 Patched (2021-06-20 r80951)
132 Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
133 Running under: macOS Big Sur 10.16
134
135 Matrix products: default
136 BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
137 LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
138
139 locale:
140 [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
141
142 attached base packages:
143 [1] parallel  stats4    stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets
144 [8] methods   base
145
146 other attached packages:
147  [1] plyranges_1.10.0     forcats_0.5.1        stringr_1.4.0
148  [4] dplyr_1.0.8          purrr_0.3.4          readr_2.1.2
149  [7] tidyr_1.2.0          tibble_3.1.6         ggplot2_3.3.6
150 [10] tidyverse_1.3.1      GenomicRanges_1.42.0 GenomeInfoDb_1.26.7
151 [13] IRanges_2.24.1       S4Vectors_0.28.1     BiocGenerics_0.36.1
152
153 loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
154  [1] lattice_0.20-45             lubridate_1.8.0
155  [3] Rsamtools_2.6.0             Biostrings_2.58.0
156  [5] assertthat_0.2.1            rprojroot_2.0.3
157  [7] utf8_1.2.2                  R6_2.5.1
158  [9] cellranger_1.1.0            backports_1.4.1
159 [11] reprex_2.0.1                httr_1.4.3
160 [13] pillar_1.7.0                zlibbioc_1.36.0
161 [15] rlang_1.0.2                 readxl_1.4.0
162 [17] rstudioapi_0.13             Matrix_1.4-1
163 [19] BiocParallel_1.24.1         RCurl_1.98-1.6
164 [21] munsell_0.5.0               DelayedArray_0.16.3
165 [23] broom_0.8.0                 rtracklayer_1.50.0
166 [25] compiler_4.0.5              modelr_0.1.8
167 [27] pkgconfig_2.0.3             tidyselect_1.1.2
168 [29] SummarizedExperiment_1.20.0 GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.4
169 [31] matrixStats_0.61.0          XML_3.99-0.9
170 [33] fansi_1.0.3                 crayon_1.5.1
171 [35] tzdb_0.3.0                  dbplyr_2.1.1
172 [37] withr_2.5.0                 GenomicAlignments_1.26.0
173 [39] bitops_1.0-7                grid_4.0.5
174 [41] jsonlite_1.8.0              gtable_0.3.0
175 [43] lifecycle_1.0.1             DBI_1.1.3
176 [45] magrittr_2.0.3              scales_1.2.0
177 [47] cli_3.2.0                   stringi_1.7.6
178 [49] XVector_0.30.0              fs_1.5.2
179 [51] xml2_1.3.3                  ellipsis_0.3.2
180 [53] generics_0.1.2              vctrs_0.4.0
181 [55] tools_4.0.5                 Biobase_2.50.0
182 [57] glue_1.6.2                  hms_1.1.1
183 [59] MatrixGenerics_1.2.1        colorspace_2.0-3
184 [61] rvest_1.0.2                 haven_2.4.3
185 [63] usethis_2.1.6
186 >
```